How to pass chrome profile to jpgc@ Chrome driver config in jmeter
I am trying to take the full page screenshot with Fireshot API. Below is the sample code in @Jpgc Webdriver Sampler:
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import java.io.File
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

try {
    // Navigate to the webpage

    WDS.browser.get("https://example.com")

    // Wait for the page to load completely
    WDS.browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    // Capture full-page screenshot using FireShot
    String screenshotPath = "D:/API/fullpage_screenshot.png"
    def screenshotBase64 = WDS.browser.executeScript("return FireShotAPI.base64EncodePage(true);")
    byte[] decodedBytes = screenshotBase64.decodeBase64()
    File screenshotFile = new File(screenshotPath)
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(screenshotFile, decodedBytes)

    // Log the screenshot path
    WDS.log.info("Screenshot saved at: " + screenshotPath)

    // Close the browser
    WDS.browser.quit()
} catch (Exception e) {
    WDS.log.error("Error capturing screenshot: " + e.getMessage())
}

It gives error:

2024-12-05 19:18:27,646 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Error capturing screenshot: javascript error: FireShotAPI is not defined
(Session info: chrome=131.0.6778.109)

I want to pass the google profile created with Fireshot plugin to kicked off during the chrome driver initialization. Is there any option for the same.

You need to go to "Capabilities Management" tab of the Chrome Driver Config and specify your user dir and profile dir there:

More information:

How to open a Chrome Profile through --user-data-dir argument of Selenium
How to Use JMeter for Selenium WebDriver Testing


Thanks for the inputs,....I tried above but it seems jmeter is always creating a temp profile for chrome. When i checked the launch browser version it is showing the path as "..AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6156_304050167\Default". Above solution should override this but it is not working for me...Note, scoped_dir is random.

You can try switching to JSR223 Sampler with Groovy language and initialize WebDriver yourself, this way you will get full control
